# Have user enter data in jagged array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, user-input, jagged-arrays

I am new to jagged arrays in C# and can't seem to figure out how to use them.

I am trying to use a jagged array to hold the number of weeks a guy worked (which is hard coded to 4), then how many days he worked each week and hold the value of how much he made each week.

Then I want the user to enter how many days worked for each week then ask how much money was made each day and have the user enter that, but I can't seem to figure out how to create a loop to do that.

```
double[][] earningsArray = new double[4][]; 
//4 = the amount of weeks of work
// then the empty spot = how many days worked that week
```

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 3):

You need 2 loops to do this

**First** loop is for *reading* days of work and **allocate** memory for days in that week.

**Second** loop is for *reading* money earned each day and assign it to jagged array.

```
var weeksOfWork = 4;
double[][] earningsArray = new double[weeksOfWork][];
for (int weekIndex = 0; weekIndex < weeksOfWork; weekIndex++)
{
    var daysOfWork = // read days of work
    earningsArray[weekIndex] = new double[daysOfWork]; // allocate memory for days
    for(int dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < daysOfWork; dayIndex++)
    {
         var moneOfDay= // read money earned that day
         earningsArray[weekIndex][dayIndex] = moneyOfDay; // introduce money in a specific day of week
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a good case for a jagged array of doubles.

Why not have an array of strongly-typed workweek summaries:

```
public class WorkweekSummary
{
    public WorkweekSummary()
    {
        MoneyMadeOnDay = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, double>();
    }

    public int DaysWorked { get{ return MoneyMadeOnDay.Count; } 
    public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, double> MoneyMadeOnDay{ get; private set; }
}

var workweekSummaries = new WorkweekSummary[4];
```

You can then have an array of WorkWeekSummary, and loop through it, filling out workday information if the user has entered it for given days.

The number of days they worked is inferred from the entries added to the MoneyMadeOnDay dictionary, so you eliminate a step in the data entry.